# Cannot boot Ubuntu with a Samsung dual graphics card 305V5A-s02 notebook

Tags: drivers, ati, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to boot 11.10 due to graphic driver problem with ati Radeon HD6470M o Amd A8 quad core. These are the things I have tried so far](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89952/unable-to-boot-11-10-due-to-graphic-driver-problem-with-ati-radeon-hd6470m-o-amd)

I need to download a driver for my graphics card as I cant boot ubuntu. How\where can I download it so I can run it from the laptop into ubuntu as I cant see anything. As I cant also save it to downloads if I only have windows to make the download and windows cant see\save to ubuntu downloads folder.
thanks

Ok I have to set `nomodeset` first in F6 or it just freezes with cd going aver and over.

Doing this allows me to boot from from CD and work ok in live CD mode.

I've installed ubuntu. Now I can't boot.

Taking out `quietsplash`, I tried `nomodeset` in my grub but only got to `battery line`..
have tried both 11.10 64bit and 32 bit on the samsung but  have this boot issue after installation. Could use a 10.04 CD which I can boot with on the Samsung and use in "Try Ubuntu mode"? ould use "try ubuntu" mode when booting from the 11.10 CD (both 32bit and 64bit)? Would it be worth installing 10.04 on the samsung would the Radeon HD6470M driver be correct there or would it be better to try 11.04 maybe. Please sigest.Thanks

`nomodeset xforcevesa` and `xforcevesa` just gives purple screen followed by purple screen with 20% white virticle lines at top then goes to nothing only black screen and freeze.

I ran try cd with `nomodeset` now after `lspci | grep VGA` we have.

`00:01.0 VGA compatable controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 9641` Then...

`02:00.0 VGA compatable controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon H D 6470M].`

This is a brand new Samsung 305V5A-s02 notebook which doesnt allow me to remove the extra graphics card.

If I try to run sudo apt-get install fglrx -installer......it tells me unable to locate fglrx -installer

Comment: ... just trying to pin down what you have just said... You have tried both 11.10 64bit and 32 bit on the samsung but you have this boot issue after installation.  You can use a 10.04 CD which you can boot with on the Samsung and use in "Try Ubuntu mode"?  You also can use "try ubuntu" mode when booting from the 11.10 CD (both 32bit and 64bit)?  Does installing 10.04 on the samsung work and you can boot correctly?

Comment: BTW I ran startx and besides many things its said Failed to load fgirx (module does not exist) also other seemingly important lines if you need to know. Thanks

Comment: Yes more or less to all. I didnt know about nomedeset when I first tried 64 so I havnt used it since. I havnt tried to load 10.04 on Samsung as I downloaded 11.10 presuming drivers more modern. I am happy to try any combinations you think might help. I have had advise about installing latest driver into home\antony\etc but as I can see the directories I would need to find a way to copy a downloaded driver into there. I have also looked at sudo apt-get remove radeon-* but there is a sever warning message so didnt proceed.. Thanks

Comment: @fossfreedom So anyway when you have a second maybe you can advise regards  what you descrive as safe-mode as I can see any options for safe and didnt think it had it. Thanks Tony

Comment: @Antony Please put what you have been trying in your question not the comments, that way all the information we need to help you is up front.