# Unable to boot 11.10 due to graphics driver problem with ATI Radeon HD6470M on AMD A8 Quad-Core

Tags: drivers, system-installation, amd-graphics, radeon, hd6470m

I bought a new laptop with an AMD A8 Quad-Core processor. It has dual graphics with an on board ATI Radeon HD6470M card and H6620G.
After a lot of effort, I managed to install 11.10 by using <kbd>F6</kbd> and [`nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/a/186301/955434).
Unfortunately, the installed Ubuntu won't boot, it just goes to a black screen.
These are the actions I have tried so far:

Taking out [`quiet splash`](https://askubuntu.com/q/716957/955434), I tried `nomodeset` in GRUB, but only got to the battery line. I have tried both 11.10 64-bit and 32-bit on this Samsung machine, but I get this boot issue after installation (11.10 32b currently installed). I could use a 10.04 CD which I already have or download another version if someone thinks it will work?

Other things tried:

`nomodeset xforcevesa` and `xforcevesa` just gives a purple screen followed by purple screen with 20% white verticle lines at top then goes to a black-only screen and freezes.

I ran Try CD with `nomodeset` Now, after [`lspci | grep VGA`](https://askubuntu.com/a/583693/955434) we have:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatable controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 9641 Then...
02:00.0 VGA compatable controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon H D 6470M].
```

This is a brand new Samsung 305V5A-s02 notebook which doesn't allow me to remove the extra graphics card.

If I try to run `sudo apt-get install fglrx -installer`, it tells me:

> unable to locate fglrx -installer

I ran [`startx`](https://askubuntu.com/q/518454/955434) and it tells me:

> Failed to load fgirx (module does not exist,0)

I can't download the driver using `wget` so I downloaded the Linux driver for my card from ati.com and put it onto a flash drive that I have formatted to FAT, but can't seem to work out how to load it into Ubuntu now; I thought that if I could manually install the driver maybe that would be a fix.

Someone told me that I can't use the ATI driver telling me that "Your graphics card is not listed as supported here: wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware". However, I have seen [a question where people have resolved the issue with the same card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54095/how-to-install-driver-for-amd-radeon-hd6470m).

I heard about open source too, but I am not clear about what and how that affects me.
I have a lot more information regarding what I have tried if someone is able to help and needs further information.

I believe that if the ATI site gives me that Linux driver for my card then it should be possible to fix Ubuntu.
Can someone explain how it works, and if I must accept that my laptop will only run in Windows7 or if there is a solution?
Would it be worth trying another OS like Mint etc., if not?

Answer (score 1):

as I have a similar model, maybe the following [report about installing Debian](http://bit.ly/wvDPkC) can help.