# Cannot find 'nodmraid' when installing ubuntu 13.10 under UEFI with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to Linux, and I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my Windows 8.1 tablet, Acer W700. I meet the problem `ubi-partman failed with exit code 10`. People say to solve the problem by press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select *nodmraid* when booted from usb disk. But I cannot find <kbd>F6</kbd>, neither *nodmraid*.

The boot menu shows:

```
Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects
```

And at the bottom:

```
Use the + and - keys to select which entry is highlighted.

Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands before booting or 'c' for a command-line. ESC to return previous menu."
```

How can I 'nodmraid'?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your tablet [Acer Iconia W700](https://www.wired.com/2013/01/acer-iconia-w700/) maps the Function key into some weird combination for making the keyboard a little smaller ([found here](https://www.wired.com/2013/01/acer-iconia-w700/)). I don't have the device, but from the review I've known that, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> key. So, I think the <kbd>F6</kbd> is mapped to something like <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> key (later verified it from the screenshot [here](https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/blogs/reviews/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/121219_acerW7_0085.jpg)). So, press that key combination to bring the context menu for boot parameter passing.

Check the screenshot below to see the combination

[image: acer icon w700 f6 key combination]

This question has information that might be useful

- [What are the F6 options during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186296/what-are-the-f6-options-during-installation)

<sup>Image courtesy: The review linked with the answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I've already installed Ubuntu on my tablet PC with Windows 8.1.
I haven't found *nodmraid*, instead I formatted my free space to ext3 by *EaseUS Partition Master* in Windows and reburned a live usb disk.