# Installation of 18.04 Bionic fails on XenServer7

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, xen

I tried to install Bionic server as a guest on XenServer 7.0. After booting the iso I get a black terminal saying:

```
vbd vbd-5696: 19 xenbus_dev_probe on device/vbd/5696
```

And that's it. Did anyone have more success or can point me to a way to resolve this?

Comment: There seems to be no internet-available information on Ubuntu 18.04 and Xenserver, probably because it is not a supported guest OS.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 IS now supported on Xenserver 7.6CR.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE: Ubuntu 18.04 IS supported on Xenserver 7.6CR**
see release notes here: here: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver/current-release/whats-new.html

and [Supported Guest Operating Systems updated August 15th](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver/current-release/system-requirements/guest-os-support.html).

Ubuntu 18.04 is still **not** a supported guest on Citrix Xenserver 7.0, and it isn't even a supported guest on [Xenserver 7.5CR as of May 2018](https://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/current-release/downloads/xenserver-vm-users-guide.pdf).  So, Your Mileage May Vary.

[This fellow](https://www.virtualzero.net/blog/how-to-create-an-ubuntu-server-18.04-virtual-machine-on-citrix-xenserver) has successfully installed the 18.04 Server (liveCD version) on an unknown version of xenserver, but his notes are vague.

**You *can* get it to boot** in Xenserver by choosing **EDD=on** and **nolapic** from the installer boot parameters by pressing  <kbd>F6</kbd> at the first boot screen.
What do these options do?  There's a great explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186296/what-are-the-f6-options-during-installation).

Reference:

If you edit the [installer boot entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)  and remove `quiet splash ---` you will likely see a kernel boot messages like:

> BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-June25, 0 devices found
>
> EDD information not available.

....just before the booting stops.
Please note that the VM doesn't hang or crash, it just waits forever.

I found that the ubiquity installer hangs at the start of "Copying Files" and does not continue.

Attempts to install Ubuntu server 18.04 also required EDD=on and nolapic, and although the install was successful, the first boot required adding EDD=on and nolapic to the kernel parameters, and once booted network adapter was unable to communicate.