# lightdm doesn't show up

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm

whenever I reboot the lightdm display the mouse cursor but it doesn't show the login form. However if I type my password I login into my account. This hapens since I've moved to kubuntu 15.04 (upgrade from kubuntu 14.10). I've reinstalled lightdm and it keeps doing the same thing. Any ideas?
Thkx,
Pedro.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you should probably report this on the [lightdm launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+filebug).

Comment: Definitely a bug. I've seen multiple questions like that, ever since 15.04 version.  I suggest you switch to gdm for now, or boot to tty1, login, and run `startx` or `startx unity -- :0` . You're probably gonna see xterm window with that last command pop up, which is normal if you don't have your desired session added to `.xinit` file. Link related http://askubuntu.com/a/519164/295286

Comment: Sorry, mechanically wronte `startx unity`. You're probably will want `kde`. Also easier one`startx $(which kde)`

Comment: Could you try my answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/697529/26246 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug and affects me too.
Switching to SDDM works for me. Switching from lightdm to SDDM is as follows:

Run the following and select sddm, and then do a restart:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then select sddm.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   unity --replace
```

and it might work fine this way

Comment: Just confirm me, but unity is for ubuntu, not Kubuntu, right? I think i don't have unity installed... (I don't have the computer near me)