# Cannot set lowest color depths

Tags: nvidia, xorg, colors, color-depth

Want to change color depth to something like 1 or 4.
With xorg.conf *DefaultDepth* it won't load anything other than blinking cursor if is set under 8.

`startx -- -depth` works with 16+ bit.
`Xorg -depth` gives errors.

`xdpyinfo` outputs depths: 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 24, 32 are supported.

Lowest I got (8bit) is inefficient as xorg uses constantly 30% cpu.

xenial, nvidia 304.131.

Comment: AFAIK, modern graphic adapters droped support for modes lower then 16bit. I was looking for such accessibility solution (grayscale or monochrome) but nothing in the horizon , may be only color filters if the compositing manager support that like with Compiz it has partial grayscale (Only Unity launcher stay in color). Another not perfect solution is using themes.

Comment: Thank you very much, although, I'm using i3wm and also filters aren't way to go for me.

Comment: You can try `Xnest` also, but I do not think that you can use a depth that is not native in the real server. Tried a bit to no avail... http://askubuntu.com/a/519164/16395 . You can check the screens/depths  you have available with `xdpyinfo` (I have only 24 and 32 planes).

Comment: You can also check http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb (never used)

Comment: Managed to set it to 8 bit with _xorg.conf_ but only some programs work (e.g i3wm and google-chrome). _**tty**_, gedit, nautilus etc. don't work.
Satisfying is that nvidia-smi shows 3mb vram usage.
Will try your solutions soon.