# Ubuntu 20.04 starts the TTY session instead of loading of the GUI

Tags: gui, tty

From recent, when I am starting my PC, after the maker logo I see this (sorry for the image, I can't copy this):

[image]

Then, Ubuntu asks me for the user ID:

[image]

If to input this and the password, it will be the simple terminal session.
Wee, but where did the GUI go?
Working with the PC, I need the GUI, not the terminal.

Comment: Do you see gdm screen (login screen)? Please provide more info.

Comment: @AakuraPyakura Thank you for the comment. I have recorded the cold startup to the video ([Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FJ5uk0iNqXOvBhKU4NvU1Swlj9WwGCP/view?usp=drive_link)). Nothing happen about for the one minute (as in 1st screenshot), when the OS ask me for the user ID (2nd screenshot).

Comment: So, have you tried logging in with credentials? If not, login and then try command `startx` command [more on startx](https://askubuntu.com/a/519164/957192). This command will try to start XOrg session. I am not sure why this happens, but I have seen randomly this type of issue popping and `startx` has helped me.

Comment: @AakuraPyakura "Have you tried logging in with credentials?" - Yes, the console interface works fine. "If not, login and then try command `startx` command" - the output was: `exec: /usr/bin/X: not found`, `xinit: giving up`, `unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`, `server error`. ". I am not sure why this happens" the possible cause is the error during Ubuntu updating.

Comment: Then with the information I have right now, you should use a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu. Boot it on live and first backup if you need any files from root partition to home partition or another disk if you have any. Then reinstall OS using advanced option. While on disk management during installation select new root partition as old existing one and check mark format option and if backed up in old home then check `/home` partition and continue to install. The xorg and related display server errors should be solved now.

Comment: @AakuraPyakura, Looks like the OS is dead and it's more simpler to make the clean installation...