# lspci does not recognize my gpu

Tags: 16.04, radeon, msi, amdgpu-pro

I have been walking through the instructions on the amd website: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx. I want to set up my r9 390x gpus on my new mobo, with ubuntu 16.04 and the amdgpu-pro package.

However, when I install ubuntu, I am never able to see the gpu that i have plugged in. This happens whether I have it plugged in via a usb riser or directly, regardless of the slot, and regardless of whether I power it through a molex/sata or through the main 8-pin plug on top.

I have read similar posts like this where the OP did not know what to look for: 
[lspci | grep VGA does not detect my dedicated AMD Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230 in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583689/lspci-grep-vga-does-not-detect-my-dedicated-amd-radeon-hd-8550m-r5-m230-in-u)

I do not have the same situation because the output of `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` shows only the integrated graphics controller:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 [8086:1902] (rev 06)

I have been working on this error for days now, and haven't been able to do anything that will get ubuntu to recognize my device. Nothin on the inernet that I can find about ubuntu simply ignoring my graphics card.

Some of the steps I have overcome to install amdgpu-pro so far:

- needed to downgrade ubuntu to 16.04 so that I could use the hwe versions of xserver-xorg packages. Installed all hwe packages with the `--install-recommends` option, so that I could use the required `xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro`.
- found the right version of amdgpu-pro (18 requires modesetting but 16 has a bug in it)
- upon intsalling amdgpu-pro 16/17, I am getting a warning about missing possible firmware for my onboard graphics (on the `i915` module) I fixed it by simply downloading the binaries from ubuntu and copying them into my /usr/bin directory
- just found a non-fatal error that was happening during installation that I didn't notice before -- 
  `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-33-generic (x86_64)
  Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/make.log for more information.`

I checked the log file and it suggested downloading `libelf-dev`. So I did that and then reinstalled, which caused a lot of other packages to be downloaded. It ran successfully, but this time there was a similar but different error in the log:

```
`make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/amd/amdkcl    /kcl_drm.c:1:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h: In   function ‘kcl_drm_universal_plane_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-492261/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:271:29: error: incompatible type for argument 7 of ‘drm_universal_plane_init’
  formats, format_count, type, name);
...`
```

I think its possible that this error has to do with kernel options -- not sure. But I'm not sure this even has a bearing on the initial problem. Sure, maybe amdgpu isn't installing properly -- but why isn't my gpu showing up at all?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this had nothing to do with my installation of amdgpu-pro. Very stupic mistake -- my card was not fully powered. I had the 8-pin plug connected to my PSU, but not the additional 6-pin plug that comes with these cards.

P.S. the secret for me for getting amdgpu-pro driver installed properly was using amdgpu-pro 16.60 (no longer available directly from amd for some reason, but you can find it), ubuntu 16.04.01, and installing with `./amdgpu-pro-install --px --compute` and then `sudo usermod -a -G video <user>`, followed by a full reinstall of `xorg` and `"xserver-*"`

hope that helps a newb like me...